# Node doesn't find segwit transactions

Tags: wallet, address, segregated-witness, bitcoin-knots

I had to move around wallets and so on, and when I re-installed Knots (yeah I'm that edgy), it doesn't find the transactions to my segwit addresses. I can probably find the SW addresses somewhere, but probably not the regular ones I used addwitnessaddress with. Is this solvable?

Answer (score 1):

If you are restoring a backup from before you had done `addwitnessaddress` to your addresses, then it will not know to look for the segwit scripts that correspond to your wallet. You will need to do `addwitnessaddress` again for all of your addresses and then rescan the blockchain in order for your wallet to find those transactions.

Comment: Is there a way to find the address that you used addwitnessaddress on, if you know the segwit address?

Comment: Currently, no, because the segwit addresses are actually P2SH addresses and it is impossible to know the redeemScript of a P2SH address given just the address. The redeemScript would allow you to know the non-segwit address that it corresponds to.